# ActionListener and Thread.sleep

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, event-dispatch-thread

I have a JButton, which, as soon as I click on it, I want to change some colors after a few seconds, for example from blue -> 1 sec -> red -> 1 sec -> yellow. My problem is that, as soon as I use the Thread.sleep function in ActionListener and I test my program, it freezes for the 2 seconds and gives me directly yellow. How can I fix that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

> ActionListener and Thread.sleep..

..don't play well together.

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.